# I got this error trying to create a While loop in swift: Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop, swiftui, control-flow

I'm trying to create a swift app that gets the current time and then creates a countdown that ends at midnight. This is my first swift project and I really don't know whats going on. If anyone can help me I would appreciate it a lot, thanks!

The error I get: Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

The code:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  RealClock
//
//  Created by Milos Dragan Ivancic Santana on 3/1/22.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var hour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
    @State var minute = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
    @State var second = Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())
    @State var realHour:Int = 0
    @State var realMinute:Int = 0
    @State var realSecond:Int = 0
    @State var isTimeShown:Bool = false
    
    func time() {
        realHour = 24-hour
        realMinute = 60-minute
        realSecond = 60-second
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
            ZStack {
                
                VStack{
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    HStack {
                    
                            
                        while true { **I get the error here**
                            if isTimeShown {
                                
                                Text(String(realHour))
                                Text(":")
                                Text(String(realMinute))
                                Text(":")
                                Text(String(realSecond))
                                
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }.padding(.bottom, 100)
                    
                    HStack {
                       
                        Button {
                            
                            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0, repeats: false) {
                                
                                    Timer in
                                
                                    time()
                                    isTimeShown = true
                                                            
                                
                                
                                    
                                    
                            }
                            } label: {
                                
                                Text("Press")
                                
                                
                        
                        }
                               
                        }
                     
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }

    

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
        ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is clear you can't use `while` in a `body` look into [TimelineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview)

Answer (score 0):

You aren’t able to use while or for loops in your View. However, since you made `realHour`, `realMinute`, and `realSecond` `@State` variables, they will update the view anytime they change! Simply removing the while loop works, and the values will update as soon as you press the “Press” button. As written, they only update once, because the `time()` function uses the same hour, minute, and second values each time. To get that function to work multiple times, you want to either bring the functions inside the function, like this:

```
func time() {
    realHour = 24 - Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())
    realMinute = 60 - Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())
    realSecond = 60 - Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date())
}
```

or make them [computed properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html), like this:

```
var hour: Int { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) }
var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date()) }
var second: Int { Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date()) }
```

I’ve included the full code below.

As was mentioned in the comments, [timelineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview) may be what you want if you want to bypass the “Press” button entirely. I also recommend looking into the timer; it seems like you could remove it entirely (keeping the lines inside), at least with the code you posted.

Here’s the full code that works for me:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var hour: Int { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) }
    var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date()) }
    var second: Int { Calendar.current.component(.second, from: Date()) }
    @State var realHour:Int = 0
    @State var realMinute:Int = 0
    @State var realSecond:Int = 0
    @State var isTimeShown:Bool = false
    
    func time() {
        realHour = 24-hour
        realMinute = 60-minute
        realSecond = 60-second
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack{
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    if isTimeShown {
                        Text(String(realHour))
                        Text(":")
                        Text(String(realMinute))
                        Text(":")
                        Text(String(realSecond))
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, 100)
            HStack {
                Button {
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0, repeats: false) {
                        Timer in
                        time()
                        isTimeShown = true
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Press")
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
        ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's now working for me... The code doesn't have any errors now (without the while loop) but when I run the program it shows me the time left until midnight but it doesn't change :(  Anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: Did you change the time function? If you only removed the while loop, the time function as you had it pulls from the original hour/minute/second which don’t change each time.